# UserWarning: X scores are null at iteration

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

I am trying to run CCA for a multi label/text classification problem but keep getting following warning and an error which I think are related

> warnings.warn('Maximum number of iterations reached')
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_decomposition/pls_.py:290:
>   UserWarning: X scores are null at iteration 0   warnings.warn('X
>   scores are null at iteration %s' % k)
>
> warnings.warn('Maximum number of iterations reached')
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_decomposition/pls_.py:290:
>   UserWarning: X scores are null at iteration 1

warnings.warn('X scores are null at iteration %s' % k)
...
for all the 400 iterations and then following error at the end which I think is a side effect of above warning:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "scikit_fb3.py", line 477,
>   in 
>       getCCA(shorttestfilepathPreProcessed)   File "scikit_fb3.py", line 318, in getCCA
>       X_CCA = cca.fit(x_array, Y_indicator).transform(X)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_decomposition/pls_.py",
>   line 368, in transform
>       Xc = (np.asarray(X) - self.x_mean_) / self.x_std_   File "/usr/local/bin/src/scipy/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 389, in
>   **sub**
>       raise NotImplementedError('adding a nonzero scalar to a ' NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not
>   supported

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`CCA` doesn't support sparse matrices. By default, you should assume scikit-learn estimators do *not* grok sparse matrices and check their docstrings to find out if by chance you found one that does.

(I admit the warning could have been friendlier.)

Comment: So I am passing X after running it thru HashingVectorizer fit_transform. What operation should I do on X to make it compatible with CCA?

Comment: I tried X.todense() before passing it to CCA but still same warning and error.